# Purpose of adding elements between first responder and exit

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

In Xcode 8.3.3 Interface Builder, I happened to drag and drop a UI element accidentally beyond the usual UIView and into the control bar where there is the Scene, First Responder and Exit icons. I can't seem to find documentation or guides that explain what it is used for and how to use it. Appreciate any help or directions. Hope the pictures makes it clearer.

[image: Before adding element]

[image: After adding element]